# How do I assign a wild-carded path to a property

Tags: ant, path

I have a directory, let's call it `/tmp/foo/bar_v101/scripts` that I need to assign to an ant property.  In general, I'd do it like this:

```
<property name="prop" value="/tmp/foo/bar_v101/scripts" />
```

But, the `v101` portion of the property will be changing, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
<property name="prop" value="/tmp/foo/bar_*/scripts" />
```

And the value of prop will be automatically expanded to something like this:

```
/tmp/foo/bar_v101/scripts
```

Or whatever is currently in the filesystem.  Unfortunately, this does not work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) - either `fileset` or `files` in this way:

```
<files includes="/tmp/foo/bar_*/scripts" id="my.file" />
<property name="prop" value="${toString:my.file}" />
```

Note that this will set `prop` to a semi-colon separated list of *all* matches found - which may not be useful if there is more than one.

A `fileset` works in a similar way, except that it supports a `dir` attribute and relative paths, rather than the absolute paths used by `files`.